# How to set a color using a List and Colors with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to generate a horizontal scrollable list using a different color for each list item.
Without the 'loop' provided by ListView.builder, I can define a color swatch using `Colors.red` , to get the color red, for instance.

The 'property' indicator of the Colors object does not work using the method I tried below, using the swatch names in the type of String.

What is the right type to use?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubscriptionFilter extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> colors = <String>['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 75.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: colors.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors[index],
          );
        }
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing colors as 'red' or 'blue' will not work, you need to modify code like below.

```
class SubscriptionFilter extends StatelessWidget  {

  final List<Color> colors = <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue,Colors.amber];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 75.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: colors.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: colors[index],
          );
        }
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change List to List
2. Use colors[index] and not Colors[index] and it will work for you.

Following is the working code for your reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubscriptionFilter extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Color> colors = <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.green, Colors.yellow, Colors.orange];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 75.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: colors.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: colors[index],
          );
        }
    ),
    );
  }
}
```